# Dismiss Chat flags when I delete the message

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags, moderator-tools

So someone flags a message in chat with a mod-only message. Upon deleting the post, the flag is still there as is the UI element. I have to manually dismiss the flag even if I agree and delete the post.  A very very common use case for these flags is "I did something stupid, please delete it":

[image]

There's really nothing else to do here in almost all cases, and if I need to go suspend "derp" here, not dismissing the flag doesn't really help me, as I'll already have pulled up the transcript (linked from the room name) or their user profile (linked by their name).

Can these mod-only chat flags be dismissed when a post is deleted? Once you've acted upon it that seems like it's implicitly dismissing it. Dismissing upon action would follow the same convention as acting on post flags; closing/deleting a flagged post dismisses those flags.

Comment: This seems reasonable, the flagging system on the Q&A portion of the site works this way. I suppose it's implemented in chat the way it is so that a pattern of behavior by particular problematic users can still be easily detected, even after the offending comments are knee-jerk removed?